# Android LinearLayout not displaying correctly if number of items is lesser then screen height

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I have a fragment which fetch items from rest api and display the item title in LinearLayout within a scrollview.

Below are my views and codes.

fragment_cards_view.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@color/wallet_holo_blue_light"/>

</ScrollView>
```

list_item.xml

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        style="@style/item_header"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

TitleFragment.java

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "In onCreateView");

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cards_view, container, false);

        mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.linear_card_view);

        return v;
    }

private void createUpcomingView() {  
            int counter = 0;
            for (User user : mUsers) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = null;
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View mLinearView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                mLinearView.setId(user.getId());

                TextView titleTextView = (TextView)mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.list_titleTextView);
                titleTextView.setText("title " + counter);
                mLinearLayout.addView(mLinearView);
                counter++;
            }
        }
```

The problem I faced is that if the number of items is lesser than the screen height, the display becomes incorrect.

This screenshot has 4 items, but it is only showing the first item and the margins are not aligned correctly.
[image]

This screenshot has many items and the margins are aligned correctly.
[image]

This screenshot is the first solution:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove following layout from list_item.xml then it will work properly.

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hi, the marginRight problem still persists after removing the child relativeLayout

Comment: where you want margin?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, mLinearLayout, false);
```

instead of

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
```

Also, use wrap_content heights in list_item.xml

Comment: Hi, tks for the reply. I have added mLinearLayout to inflater and set wrap_contents to the two relativeLayout in list_item.xml. I have uploaded another screenshot showing the result. Apparently, the margin is off..

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution based on the answers from @clemp6r and @Jain Nidhi.

fragment_cards_view.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/wallet_holo_blue_light"/>

</ScrollView>
```

list_item.xml, add left and right margin, removed nested RelativeLayout, set all layout_height to wrap_content

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        style="@style/item_header"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

TitleFragment.java, modified the 2nd and 3rd argument of inflate.

```
private void createUpcomingView(..) {
View mLinearView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, mLinearLayout, false);
}
```